# Same SSRS report, two different subscription names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I would like to know how to change same SSRS reports from one subscription name to two different “from” names?

Comment: Hope this helps you. [How to specify different from addresses for difference subscription recipients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909901/how-to-specify-different-from-addresses-for-difference-subscription-recipients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update XML code in report database tables(after report deployed in report server then need to create subscription, its data will be stored in sql table by xml format) with required format.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example with table name, column name, node of xml etc?